# LibreOffice Writer 5.4.6.2: Bengali language paragraph alignment isn't properly Justified

Tags: 17.10, libreoffice

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm using **LibreOffice 5.4.6.2** in **Ubuntu 17.10** operating system. Both of my  **Locale setting** and the **Complex text layout** setting are set to **Bengali (Bangladesh)**. I use **IBus m17n** as the *language input method* to write Bangla/Bengali texts.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I use the **Format** - **Paragraph** - **Alignment tab** - **Option** - **Justified** command, the Bengali language paragraphs in my **.odt** documents do not get justified properly. The right side of the alignment gets *unevenly* justified. Moreover, the spaces between the words — and the spaces between the words and the punctuation marks — are *unevenly distributed*. That is to say, there are *false spaces* appearing randomly here and there in the paragraphs. Please see the screenshot:

[image: file attached herewith.]

If I try to delete such a *false space* by putting the cursor to the *right side* of the "space" and hit the *Backspace Key*, the "space" doesn't delete; it actually deletes the immediate next character to the *left* of the cursor.

*Please tell me how to fix the problem.*

**TWO CLUES**

*Clue One*: When I convert the same Bengali language paragraphs to any of English language fonts like **Liberation Serif** the justification alignment and spaces become absolutely perfect.

*Clue Two*: English language paragraphs in the same document (even if they are converted to some Bengali language font like **Lohit Bengali**) shows no such trouble. They are just okay.

Comment: Which font?  In my experience, LO renders some Devanagari fonts better than others, so the same is probably true for Bangla script as well.  Also, try exporting to a PDF file and see if the problem occurs when opened in a PDF viewer.  Or similarly, see if the problem occurs when the document is printed.

Comment: All Bengali fonts in my computer. For example, **Lohit Bengali**, **AponaLohit**, **Mukti Narrow**, **Ekushey Amar Bangla**,  **Ani**, **Bangla**, **BenSen**, **Likhan**, **Mitra Mono**, **Siyam Rupali**, etc.

Please clarify what do you mean by **LO**? *Lohit Odia*? Yes, LO renders perfect. Not only LO, but many other Non-Bangali fonts work okay. But That does not solve my problem. They all look like *Mukti Narrow*. 

The problem remains when exported to a PDF file and opened in a PDF viewer, OR when it is printed. IS IT A BUG?

Comment: LO is short for LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks, Jim K. 

I'm thinking of upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 and thereby to LO 6. I hope that will solve my problem. I've tested the 18.04 live USB.

Comment: May I use LibreOffice Writer 5.1.0.3 in Ubuntu 18.04? That version of LO didn't have this problem, I remember.