# May I use LibreOffice Writer 5.1.0.3 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: libreoffice

May I use LibreOffice **Writer** **5.1.0.3** in Ubuntu **18.04**?

The point is that I'm trying to avoid a bug ([Bug 105913](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105913)) which is there with LibreOffice 5.3 (in Ubuntu 17.10) and LibreOffice 6.0.4.2 (in Ubuntu 18.04). My **previous question** explains that problem [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032552/libreoffice-writer-5-4-6-2-bengali-language-paragraph-alignment-isnt-properly).

Is it possible to use LibreOffice Writer 5.1.0.3 in Ubuntu 18.04? That version of LibreOffice didn't have this problem, I remember.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Uninstall LibreOffice, then download [this](https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/5.1.0.3/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.1.0.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz) (from the official LibreOffice archive) and extract it, then install it.

If you need a 32-bit version instead, use [this](https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/5.1.0.3/deb/x86/LibreOffice_5.1.0.3_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz).

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot ! Gonna try it right now and I'm comming back with a feedback. God bless !

Comment: Hello @Tom, I've completely uninstall LibreOffice (all instances) from my Ubuntu 18.04 (using the command line) and then installed LibreOffice 5.1.0.3 from the package link you referred to. In addition, I've downloaded installed the language pack  and the help pack (for Bengali language) from the source.

Now, the "Show Applications" (in the dock) is showing all the LibreOffice software; and the "Software Centre" also is showing them under the "Installed" tab.

But LibreOffice is not running when I click on any one of them. It's just starting to run and then disappearing.

Help please!

Comment: When I run << libreoffice5.1 >> command from the terminal, it says the following : [[LINE BREAK]] 

srn@SRN-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ libreoffice5.1 [[LINE BREAK]] 
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment! [[LINE BREAK]] 
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx [[LINE BREAK]] 
Gtk-Message: 00:25:02.605: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" [[LINE BREAK]] 

Any help, please! @Tom 
Application Error

Comment: @SalimRezaNewton just google it...  https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/140827/javaldx-could-not-find-a-java-runtime-environment/

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I'm exploring the link and getting back soon.

Comment: Well, @Tom, by this time I've installed default JRE ( Java Runtime Environment) and OpenJDK (following these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04#prerequisites). But still, it is giving me the same message (in the terminal) as above.

I'm lucky that I'm getting you here continuously. Thanks dear.

Comment: UPDATE: The Gtk-Message has gone now after I installed the gtk module with this command line: sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module.

Comment: The other two "Application Errors, that is, << javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment! >> and << Warning: failed to read path from javaldx >> still persist.